# Discord.py adding a role through reactions

Tags: discord.py

I am using code that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52210855/give-role-when-a-user-add-reaction-discord-py).

But, I'm getting an error that the `client` object doesn't have the attribute `send_message`. I have tried `message.channel.send` but that failed as well.

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    Channel = client.get_channel('YOUR_CHANNEL_ID')
    Text= "YOUR_MESSAGE_HERE"
    Moji = await client.send_message(Channel, Text)
    await client.add_reaction(Moji, emoji='')

@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    Channel = client.get_channel('YOUR_CHANNEL_ID')
    if reaction.message.channel.id != Channel:
      return

    if reaction.emoji == "":
      Role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="YOUR_ROLE_NAME_HERE")
      await client.add_roles(user, Role)
```

Comment: Have you tried `Moji = client.send(Channel, Text)`?

Comment: What version of discord.py are you using?

Comment: yes I have it says client doesn't have attribute send

Comment: And version 1.0.1 on repl.it

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons why your code might not be working is because you may have your `channel id` stored in a string. Your code shows:

```py
Channel = client.get_channel('YOUR CHANNEL ID')
```

The code above shows that your `channel id` is stored in a string, which it should not be. With the code above, your actual code may look like this:

```py
Channel = client.get_channel('1234567890')
```

Instead you should have:

```py
Channel = client.get_channel(1234567890)
```

Comment: Oh yea thanks for that, fixed it in my actual code but would you happen to know whats wrong if not that

Comment: I got the first part to work but it won't assign a role