# Discord Error: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'message' is not defined in role reaction

Tags: discord.py

Hello for my bot I put an auto role system but alas when I run my code its said to me:

`NameError: name 'message' is not define`

can u help me pls
the code:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    Channel = client.get_channel('829747866360610843')
    Text= "Hey Si Tu Veux Acceder Au Conversations Exclusivement Pour Les Mangas Clique Sur La Réaction  !"
    Moji = await message.channel.send(Channel, Text)
    await client.add_reaction(Moji, emoji='')
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    Channel = client.get_channel('829747866360610843')
    if reaction.message.channel.id != Channel:
        return
    if user.reaction.emoji == "":
        Role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="manga")
        await client.add_roles(user, Role)
```

Comment: This method is pretty outdated and just copy & past from another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52210855/give-role-when-a-user-add-reaction-discord-py?rq=1). Please give us the whole traceback even though the error is self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your on_ready event: `Moji = await message.channel.send(Channel, Text)`
There is no variable called message there, my guess is you're trying to send the message to that channel you got earlier, to do so, you should use `Moji = await Channel.send(Text)`.
Also: when using add_reaction, it's suggested to use the one from the message, and not from the client: `await Moji.add_reaction('')`