# I've been developing my reaction roles feature in discord.py, it's not working

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, roles

I made a post about this yesterday and the code I was given didn't work, every time I try to run the command on a server that doesn't have the He/Him role, it gives me an error message saying that I have missing permissions

```
@bot.command(name='rolecreate', help='creates all the default roles')
@has_permissions(manage_messages=True, manage_roles=True)
async def rolecreate(ctx):
  Text= "React with :heart: to get the He/Him role!"
  Moji1 = await ctx.send(Text)
  reaction="❤️"
  await Moji1.add_reaction(reaction)
  @bot.listen() 
  async def on_reaction_add(reaction, member):
    if reaction.message.channel.id != 881380132789583892:
      return
    if reaction.emoji == "❤️":
                he_him = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="He/Him")     

    if not he_him:
      he_him = await member.guild.create_role(name="He/Him")
```

Comment: does the bot have the manage roles permissions ? Without it you cannot create a role

Comment: @Scuffedsimon Its happening due to what LeSauvage said. In your server settings, place the bot role above the role you want to give to the users when they react and then give the bot manage roles permission by clicking on its role

Comment: It's at the top of the code, second line

Comment: @ChaoticNebula the role doesn't exist on the server and it's giving me a missing permissions error whenever I try to use it, despite the bot having full admin perms

Comment: In the discord developer portal, did you select the "bot" scope in OAuth2 settings and did you give it the necessary perms? If not so, I would recommend to re-invite the bot after doing this.

Comment: @ChaoticNebula Ok so the bot can now create the roles but it isn't adding them when I react, any ideas? also it's creating the role 6 times

Comment: @ChaoticNebula update: it's not creating the role 6 times anymore

Comment: Does it show any error? and check again if the bot's role is placed above the role created

Comment: @ChaoticNebula no errors for some reason, it's just not adding the role

Comment: There is no ```add_roles() ```method.

Comment: where would I add that?

Comment: After you get the role or create the role

Comment: what line of code would I need to use for that?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52210855/give-role-when-a-user-add-reaction-discord-py) stackoverflow question might help

Comment: a modified version of that code is what I've been working off of this whole time

Comment: ```member.add_roles(member, role)``` Use this line

Comment: Ok that broke it, now whenever I run the command it gives me a 404 not found error in the console, despite me having an if not statement that should be stopping that

Comment: role1=He/Him by the way 

@bot.listen() 
  async def on_reaction_add(reaction, member):
    if reaction.message.channel.id != 881773143113490442:
      return
    if reaction.emoji == "❤️":
                he_him = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name=role1)     
                await member.add_roles(member, role1)
    if not he_him:
      he_him = await member.guild.create_role(name=role1)
      await member.add_roles(member, role1)

crap it didn't format

Answer (score 0):

hello this is my reaction roles and it works great make sure to make the json file and stuff

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json
import atexit
import uuid
import datetime

x = datetime.datetime.now()

reaction_roles_data = {}

try:
    with open("reaction_roles.json") as file:
        reaction_roles_data = json.load(file)
except (FileNotFoundError, json.JSONDecodeError) as ex:
    with open("reaction_roles.json", "w") as file:
        json.dump({}, file)


@atexit.register
def store_reaction_roles():
    with open("reaction_roles.json", "w") as file:
        json.dump(reaction_roles_data, file)


class ReactionRoles(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f"ReactionRoles ready.")

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload: discord.RawReactionActionEvent):
        role, user = self.parse_reaction_payload(payload)
        if role is not None and user is not None:
            await user.add_roles(role, reason="ReactionRole")

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload: discord.RawReactionActionEvent):
        role, user = self.parse_reaction_payload(payload)
        if role is not None and user is not None:
            await user.remove_roles(role, reason="ReactionRole")

    @commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
    @commands.cooldown(1, 5, BucketType.user)
    @commands.command()
    async def reaction(
        self,
        ctx,
        emote,
        role: discord.Role,
        channel: discord.TextChannel,
        title,
        message,
    ):
        commandd = "reaction"
        print(f"{ctx.author.name}, {ctx.author.id} used command "+commandd+" used at ")
        print(x)
        print(" ")
        embed = discord.Embed(title=title, description=message)
        msg = await channel.send(embed=embed)
        await msg.add_reaction(emote)
        self.add_reaction(ctx.guild.id, emote, role.id, channel.id, msg.id)

    @commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
    @commands.cooldown(1, 5, BucketType.user)
    @commands.command()
    async def reaction_add(
        self, ctx, emote, role: discord.Role, channel: discord.TextChannel, message_id
    ):
        commandd = "reaction_add"
        print(f"{ctx.author.name}, {ctx.author.id} used command "+commandd+" used at ")
        print(x)
        print(" ")
        self.add_reaction(ctx.guild.id, emote, role.id, channel.id, message_id)
        await ctx.send('Please enter the command like this: .reaction add (emote)  (role (ping or id))  (channel (ping or id))  "(message title)" “(message)”')
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
    @commands.cooldown(1, 5, BucketType.user)
    @commands.command()
    async def reactions(self, ctx):
        commandd = "reactions"
        print(f"{ctx.author.name}, {ctx.author.id} used command "+commandd+" used at ")
        print(x)
        print(" ")
        guild_id = ctx.guild.id
        data = reaction_roles_data.get(str(guild_id), None)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Reaction Roles")
        if data is None:
            embed.description = "There are no reaction roles set up right now."
        else:
            for index, rr in enumerate(data):
                emote = rr.get("emote")
                role_id = rr.get("roleID")
                role = ctx.guild.get_role(role_id)
                channel_id = rr.get("channelID")
                message_id = rr.get("messageID")
                embed.add_field(
                    name=index,
                    value=f"{emote} - @{role} - [message](https://www.discordapp.com/channels/{guild_id}/{channel_id}/{message_id})",
                    inline=False,
                )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    @commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
    @commands.cooldown(1, 5, BucketType.user)
    @commands.command()
    async def reaction_remove(self, ctx, index: int):
        commandd = "reaction_remove"
        print(f"{ctx.author.name}, {ctx.author.id} used command "+commandd+" used at ")
        print(x)
        print(" ")
        guild_id = ctx.guild.id
        data = reaction_roles_data.get(str(guild_id), None)
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Remove Reaction Role {index}")
        rr = None
        if data is None:
            embed.description = "Given Reaction Role was not found."
        else:
            embed.description = (
                "Do you wish to remove the reaction role below? Please react with ️."
            )
            rr = data[index]
            emote = rr.get("emote")
            role_id = rr.get("roleID")
            role = ctx.guild.get_role(role_id)
            channel_id = rr.get("channelID")
            message_id = rr.get("messageID")
            _id = rr.get("id")
            embed.set_footer(text=_id)
            embed.add_field(
                name=index,
                value=f"{emote} - @{role} - [message](https://www.discordapp.com/channels/{guild_id}/{channel_id}/{message_id})",
                inline=False,
            )
        msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        if rr is not None:
            await msg.add_reaction("️")

            def check(reaction, user):
                return (
                    reaction.message.id == msg.id
                    and user == ctx.message.author
                    and str(reaction.emoji) == "️"
                )

            reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check)
            data.remove(rr)
            await ctx.send("removed reaction")
            reaction_roles_data[str(guild_id)] = data
            store_reaction_roles()

    def add_reaction(self, guild_id, emote, role_id, channel_id, message_id):
        if not str(guild_id) in reaction_roles_data and not message.author.bot:
            reaction_roles_data[str(guild_id)] = []
        reaction_roles_data[str(guild_id)].append(
            {
                "id": str(uuid.uuid4()),
                "emote": emote,
                "roleID": role_id,
                "channelID": channel_id,
                "messageID": message_id,
            }
        )
        store_reaction_roles()

    def parse_reaction_payload(self, payload: discord.RawReactionActionEvent):
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        data = reaction_roles_data.get(str(guild_id), None)
        if data is not None:
            for rr in data:
                emote = rr.get("emote")
                if payload.message_id == rr.get("messageID"):
                    if payload.channel_id == rr.get("channelID"):
                        if str(payload.emoji) == emote:
                            guild = self.bot.get_guild(guild_id)
                            role = guild.get_role(rr.get("roleID"))
                            user = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
                            return role, user
        return None, None

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(ReactionRoles(bot))
```

-from head dev of rage bots

Comment: sorry I'm late but TYSM for this code! I don't know how to make a json file in my IDE (replit)